# Clickable Listview to open another Activity

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to make a clickable List view which's every string will open another activity when pressing those items,but I don't know how to do that in android studio...here's the code I've tried.Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String[] monthsArray = { "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY",
        "AUG", "SEPT", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC" };

private ListView monthsListView;
private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    monthsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.months_list);

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,monthsArray);
    monthsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

}

private void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {

   super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);
   String openClass = classNames[0];

    try{
       Class selected = Class.forName("com.example.anupambiswas.firststlistview." + openClass);
        Intent selectedIntent = new Intent(this,selected);
        startActivity(selectedIntent);
    }
    catch( ClassNotFoundException e){

         e.printStackTrace();

    }
}}
```

Comment: what error u r getting?

Comment: Which problem you got with your code?

Comment: I'm getting error in onlistitemclick and classnames...                                                                super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);
        String openClass = classNames[0];

Answer (score 1):

Add this in onCreate method.

```
monthsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    String openClass = classNames[0];

    try{
       Class selected = Class.forName("com.example.anupambiswas.firststlistview." + openClass);
        Intent selectedIntent = new Intent(this,selected);
        startActivity(selectedIntent);
    }
    catch( ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
});
```